# Adding attribute to HTML tags to stock data for JS manipulation

Tags: javascript, html

I building a country selection drop down that, on select, populates a city drop down.

Due to my code i need to retrieve after country selection the corresponding ISO code and unique country ID, and i would rather not query the DB again for that. So i was thinking stocking this data within the  tag, with something like this :

`<option rel='US'  someother-attribute="1" >United States</option>`

Would there be any other more straight forward way to do that ? If not what attributes could i use without impact on my HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5 data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) would be the way to go

**Setting the data in the mark-up**

*HTML Mark-Up*

```
<input id="foo" data-code="12376213jkh132kjh3" />
```

**Reading the value on the client**

*JavaScript*

```
var code = document.getElementById("foo").getAttribute("data-code");
```

I do not see the jQuery tag, but just in case it would be

*jQuery*

```
var code = $("#foo").data("code");
```